# Checking for termination when converting real to rational

Tags: algorithm, numbers

Recently I found this in some code I wrote a few years ago.  It was used to rationalize a real value (within a tolerance) by determining a suitable denominator and then checking if the difference between the original real and the rational was small enough.

*Edit to clarify* : I actually don't want to convert all real values.  For instance I could choose a max denominator of 14, and a real value that equals 7/15 would stay as-is.  It's not as clear that as it's an outside variable in the algorithms I wrote here.

The algorithm to get the denominator was this (pseudocode):

```
denominator(x)
   frac = fractional part of x
   recip = 1/frac
   if (frac < tol)
      return 1
   else
      return recip * denominator(recip)
   end
end
```

Seems to be based on continued fractions although it became clear on looking at it again that it was wrong.  (It worked for me because it would eventually just spit out infinity, which I handled outside, but it would be often really slow.)  The value for tol doesn't really do anything except in the case of termination or for numbers that end up close. I don't think it's relatable to the tolerance for the real - rational conversion.

I've replaced it with an iterative version that is not only faster but I'm pretty sure it won't fail theoretically (d = 1 to start with and fractional part returns a positive, so recip is always >= 1) :

```
denom_iter(x d)
    return d if d > maxd 
    frac = fractional part of x
    recip = 1/frac
    if (frac = 0)
        return d
    else
        return denom_iter(recip d*recip)
    end
end
```

What I'm curious to know if there's a way to pick the maxd that will ensure that it converts all values that are possible for a given tolerance.  I'm assuming 1/tol but don't want to miss something.  I'm also wondering if there's an way in this approach to actually limit the denominator size - this allows some denominators larger than maxd.

Comment: Are you opposed to using an optimization solver? Because this is clearly an integer linear program and you should be able to find a solution with such a solver.

Comment: Wouldn't it just make sense to call `round(1/tol)` your denominator? Maybe even `round(1/(10*tol))` for a little extra precision. Unless you need a fraction in lowest terms, that would seem to be the better way to go, and avoid the iterative solution completely, as long as you have a comfortable range to avoid overflow, etc., depending on what you are doing with these fractions...

Comment: I do currently round it, but I still need a way to get the denominator so something like this (or using LP as below) is still needed.  I was just trying to see if I could relate the tolerance to the choice of denominator.

Answer (score 1):

This can be considered a 2D minimization problem on error:

```
ArgMin ( r - q / p ), where r is real, q and p are integers
```

I suggest the use of  `Gradient Descent algorithm`  . The gradient in this objective function is:

```
f'(q, p) = (-1/p, q/p^2)
```

The initial guess  `r_o`  can be q being the closest integer to r, and p being 1.

The stopping condition can be thresholding of the error.

The pseudo-code of GD can be found in wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent

If the initial guess is close enough, the objective function should be convex.

---

As Jacob suggested, this problem can be better solved by minimizing the following error function:

```
ArgMin ( p * r - q ), where r is real, q and p are integers
```

This is linear programming, which can be efficiently solved by any ILP (Integer Linear Programming) solvers.  `GD`  works on non-linear cases, but lack efficiency in linear problems.

Initial guesses and stopping condition can be similar to stated above. Better choice can be obtained for individual choice of solver.

I suggest you should still assume convexity near the local minimum, which can greatly reduce cost. You can also try Simplex method, which is great on linear programming problem.

I give credit to Jacob on this.

Comment: How is this convex? `q` & `p` need to be integral. Also, what does the convexity of the objective function have to do with the initial guess?

Comment: I have no proof, therefore I said "it should be". You are welcome to provide a better answer or to disprove it.

Comment: I imagine the local minimum should form a line on 2D domain, on which the global minimum lay.

Comment: Also, iteration can restrict input to closest integers, GD should still work

Comment: The better answer would be to use an ILP solver. Also, the onus is on you to provide a proof for your solution ; not for me to disprove it.

Comment: This is not linear programming. I can plot the 2D function with discrete sampling later when I have time. It's weekdays, and I'm having lunch :P

Comment: So, minimizing `p*r-q` will not give you the same result?

Comment: I think this might be the best approach, as long as I keep a constraint on the size of q. (See edit in my question -- I don't want to convert all reals, just some subset.  Choosing a maximum for q is one approach I can take.)

Answer (score 0):

A problem similar to this is solved in the *Approximations* section beginning ca. page 28 of Bill Gosper's  *Continued Fraction Arithmetic* document.  (Ref: [postscript file](http://perl.plover.com/classes/cftalk/INFO/gosper.ps); also see [text version](http://perl.plover.com/classes/cftalk/INFO/gosper.txt), from line 1984.)  The general idea is to compute continued-fraction approximations of the low-end and high-end range limiting numbers, until the two fractions differ, and then choose a value in the range of those two approximations.  This is guaranteed to give a simplest fraction, using Gosper's terminology.

The python code below (program "simpleden") implements a similar process.  (It probably is not as good as Gosper's suggested implementation, but is good enough that you can see what kind of results the method produces.)  The amount of work done is similar to that for Euclid's algorithm, *ie* O(n) for numbers with n bits, so the program is reasonably fast.  Some example test cases (*ie* the program's output) are shown after the code itself.  Note, function `simpleratio(vlo, vhi)` as shown here returns -1 if vhi is smaller than vlo.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python    
def simpleratio(vlo, vhi):
    rlo, rhi, eps = vlo, vhi, 0.0000001
    if vhi < vlo: return -1
    num  = denp = 1
    nump = den  = 0
    while 1:
        klo, khi = int(rlo), int(rhi)
        if klo != khi or rlo-klo < eps or rhi-khi < eps:
            tlo = denp + klo * den
            thi = denp + khi * den
            if tlo < thi:
                return tlo + (rlo-klo > eps)*den
            elif thi < tlo:
                return thi + (rhi-khi > eps)*den
            else:
                return tlo            
        nump, num = num, nump + klo * num
        denp, den = den, denp + klo * den
        rlo, rhi = 1/(rlo-klo), 1/(rhi-khi)

def test(vlo, vhi):
    den = simpleratio(vlo, vhi);
    fden = float(den)
    ilo, ihi = int(vlo*den), int(vhi*den)
    rlo, rhi = ilo/fden, ihi/fden;
    izok = 'ok' if rlo <= vlo <= rhi <= vhi else 'wrong'
    print '{:4d}/{:4d} = {:0.8f}  vlo:{:0.8f}   {:4d}/{:4d} = {:0.8f}  vhi:{:0.8f}  {}'.format(ilo,den,rlo,vlo, ihi,den,rhi,vhi, izok)

test (0.685, 0.695)
test (0.685, 0.7)
test (0.685, 0.71)
test (0.685, 0.75)
test (0.685, 0.76)
test (0.75,  0.76)
test (2.173, 2.177)
test (2.373, 2.377)
test (3.484, 3.487)
test (4.0,   4.87)
test (4.0,   8.0)
test (5.5,   5.6)
test (5.5,   6.5)
test (7.5,   7.3)
test (7.5,   7.5)
test (8.534537, 8.534538)
test (9.343221, 9.343222)
```

Output from program:

```
> ./simpleden 
   8/  13 = 0.61538462  vlo:0.68500000      9/  13 = 0.69230769  vhi:0.69500000  ok
   6/  10 = 0.60000000  vlo:0.68500000      7/  10 = 0.70000000  vhi:0.70000000  ok
   6/  10 = 0.60000000  vlo:0.68500000      7/  10 = 0.70000000  vhi:0.71000000  ok
   2/   4 = 0.50000000  vlo:0.68500000      3/   4 = 0.75000000  vhi:0.75000000  ok
   2/   4 = 0.50000000  vlo:0.68500000      3/   4 = 0.75000000  vhi:0.76000000  ok
   3/   4 = 0.75000000  vlo:0.75000000      3/   4 = 0.75000000  vhi:0.76000000  ok
  36/  17 = 2.11764706  vlo:2.17300000     37/  17 = 2.17647059  vhi:2.17700000  ok
  18/   8 = 2.25000000  vlo:2.37300000     19/   8 = 2.37500000  vhi:2.37700000  ok
 114/  33 = 3.45454545  vlo:3.48400000    115/  33 = 3.48484848  vhi:3.48700000  ok
   4/   1 = 4.00000000  vlo:4.00000000      4/   1 = 4.00000000  vhi:4.87000000  ok
   4/   1 = 4.00000000  vlo:4.00000000      8/   1 = 8.00000000  vhi:8.00000000  ok
  11/   2 = 5.50000000  vlo:5.50000000     11/   2 = 5.50000000  vhi:5.60000000  ok
   5/   1 = 5.00000000  vlo:5.50000000      6/   1 = 6.00000000  vhi:6.50000000  ok
  -7/  -1 = 7.00000000  vlo:7.50000000     -7/  -1 = 7.00000000  vhi:7.30000000  wrong
  15/   2 = 7.50000000  vlo:7.50000000     15/   2 = 7.50000000  vhi:7.50000000  ok
8030/ 941 = 8.53347503  vlo:8.53453700   8031/ 941 = 8.53453773  vhi:8.53453800  ok
24880/2663 = 9.34284641  vlo:9.34322100   24881/2663 = 9.34322193  vhi:9.34322200  ok
```

If, rather than the simplest fraction in a range, you seek the best approximation given some upper limit on denominator size, consider code like the following, which replaces all the code from `def test(vlo, vhi)` forward.

```
def smallden(target, maxden):
    global pas
    pas = 0
    tol = 1/float(maxden)**2
    while 1:
        den = simpleratio(target-tol, target+tol);
        if den <= maxden: return den
        tol *= 2
        pas += 1

# Test driver for smallden(target, maxden) routine
import random
totalpass, trials, passes = 0, 20, [0 for i in range(20)]
print 'Maxden  Num Den     Num/Den       Target        Error    Passes'
for i in range(trials):
    target = random.random()
    maxden = 10 + round(10000*random.random())
    den = smallden(target, maxden)
    num = int(round(target*den))
    got = float(num)/den
    print '{:4d}  {:4d}/{:4d} = {:10.8f}  = {:10.8f} + {:12.9f}  {:2}'.format(
        int(maxden), num, den, got, target, got - target, pas)
    totalpass += pas
    passes[pas-1] += 1
print 'Average pass count: {:0.3}\nPass histo: {}'.format(
    float(totalpass)/trials, passes)
```

In production code, drop out all the references to `pas` (etc.), ie, drop out pass-counting code.

The routine `smallden` is given a target value and a maximum value for allowed denominators.  Given `maxden` possible choices of denominators, it's reasonable to suppose that a tolerance on the order of `1/maxden²` can be achieved.  The pass-counts shown in the following typical output (where `target` and `maxden` were set via random numbers) illustrate that such a tolerance was reached immediately more than half the time, but in other cases tolerances 2 or 4 or 8 times as large were used, requiring extra calls to `simpleratio`.  Note, the last two lines of output from a 10000-number test run are shown following the complete output of a 20-number test run.

```
Maxden  Num Den     Num/Den       Target        Error    Passes
1198    32/ 509 = 0.06286837  = 0.06286798 +  0.000000392   1
2136   115/ 427 = 0.26932084  = 0.26932103 + -0.000000185   1
4257   839/2670 = 0.31423221  = 0.31423223 + -0.000000025   1
2680   449/ 509 = 0.88212181  = 0.88212132 +  0.000000486   3
2935   440/1853 = 0.23745278  = 0.23745287 + -0.000000095   1
6128   347/1285 = 0.27003891  = 0.27003899 + -0.000000077   3
8041  1780/4243 = 0.41951449  = 0.41951447 +  0.000000020   2
7637  3926/7127 = 0.55086292  = 0.55086293 + -0.000000010   1
3422    27/ 469 = 0.05756930  = 0.05756918 +  0.000000113   2
1616   168/1507 = 0.11147976  = 0.11147982 + -0.000000061   1
 260    62/ 123 = 0.50406504  = 0.50406378 +  0.000001264   1
3775    52/3327 = 0.01562970  = 0.01562750 +  0.000002195   6
 233     6/  13 = 0.46153846  = 0.46172772 + -0.000189254   5
3650  3151/3514 = 0.89669892  = 0.89669890 +  0.000000020   1
9307  2943/7528 = 0.39094049  = 0.39094048 +  0.000000013   2
 962   206/ 225 = 0.91555556  = 0.91555496 +  0.000000594   1
2080   564/1975 = 0.28556962  = 0.28556943 +  0.000000190   1
6505  1971/2347 = 0.83979548  = 0.83979551 + -0.000000022   1
1944   472/ 833 = 0.56662665  = 0.56662696 + -0.000000305   2
3244   291/1447 = 0.20110574  = 0.20110579 + -0.000000051   1
Average pass count: 1.85
Pass histo: [12, 4, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The last two lines of output from a 10000-number test run:

```
Average pass count: 1.77
Pass histo: [56659, 25227, 10020, 4146, 2072, 931, 497, 233, 125, 39, 33, 17, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code demonstration.  I did read about this, but was unsure how to use it if I try to constrain the denominator to a given size. Which I suppose is more or less what I was attempting to do in my code (as it calculates the denominator at each step, I just check it but only after it's already grown too large).